# How to show decimal points when necessary?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

Html:(getting data)

```
New hourly rate: <input type="number" name="rate" />
```

I tried two method to store the `rate`.

Result.erb

```
rate= params[:rate].to_f # this works .But always show one decimal points ,like 90.5

rate= params[:rate] # String can't be coerced into Float --error
```

I want it shows the decimal points when necessary  ,like 34.5 ,45, 23.2, 33

How to improve?

Comment: do you really use `//` for commenting your Ruby code? :)

Comment: @Andrey Deineko No , i dunno how to comment the code .

Comment: edited the question for you :)

Comment: "store" and "show" are two different things.

Comment: If you don't even know how to write comments in Ruby, may I suggest first taking a simple Ruby tutorial before diving into Ruby on Rails web application development? Rails is a Ruby framework, you cannot use Rails without knowing Ruby, it's just not possible; and comments are usually one of the first things covered in any tutorial.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all having it unified is a good thing (your `to_f` conversion method).

But if you want it to be converted to different types (Float or Integer depending of decimal points presence) you can do as follows:

```
# check if params[:rate] converted to Float equals to converted to Integer
rate = if params[:rate].to_f == params[:rate].to_i
         params[:rate].to_i  # Return integer if yes
       else
         params[:rate].to_f  # Return float otherwise
       end
```

Which could be written shorted using *ternary operator*:

```
rate = params[:rate].to_f == params[:rate].to_i ? params[:rate].to_i : params[:rate].to_f

params[:rate] = '2.2'
rate = params[:rate].to_f == params[:rate].to_i ? params[:rate].to_i : params[:rate].to_f
#=> 2.2
params[:rate] = '2'
rate = params[:rate].to_f == params[:rate].to_i ? params[:rate].to_i : params[:rate].to_f
#=> 2
```

Comment: `rate = params[:rate].to_f == params[:rate].to_i ? params[:rate].to_i : params[:rate].to_f` Can u explain this sentence structure ?I don't understand this short form